# Wordpress ajax current user not updating

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Upon successful ajax submission, i am still getting back the old values. E.g.

```
$('#preview-cover').attr('src','<?php $new_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $new_user->cover); ?>");
```

This is used to call the newly uploaded image, but it is still calling the previous image. If i refresh the page, then the new image is visible.

Please advice where have i gone wrong..

Here is the result using the given code @eagle
[image: Here is the result]

Comment: you have a single quote `'` at the start of the attr property and a double quote `"` at the end, you should use one or the other

Comment: @andrew. Noted. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely caching your old file. Try:

```
$('#preview-cover').attr('src','<?php $new_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $new_user->cover); ?>?rnd=' + Math.random());
```

Comment: Nope, i am getting this in return "<img id="preview-cover" class="img-responsive" src="/uploads/2014/09/Penguins-150x112.jpg?rnd=0.9028391747269779">"

Comment: @AnilAstrio can you post what the url looks like when you refresh?